# Eddystone Url using goo.gl

Tags: url, beacon, eddystone

looking for assistance.
in the provisioning app provided with my Eddystone beacons, I have the option to input:
Url - eg - facebook
url scheme - eg 01= https://www.
Url encoded - eg 00 = .com/
Name - eg myFirstEddystoneUrl

My questions are:
How do I set it for .gl or .ly etc.
Where do i place the the rest of the url eg. https://goo.gl/**dMa9YA**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eddystone URL according to specification length should be not more then 17. So in case of long URLs, just use some URL shortener and option #1 from your app.

Comment: Thanks Dr.Lean I managed to find a work around, but it is very specific to my exact circumstance and instance.